# how to pass state to actor network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, actor-critics

let's say the state i'm expecting to pass to actor network from custom env is just [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.].

but i am getting this:

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.].

Why I'm getting extra dimension of state?
Was it because I created actor and critic network incorrectly? How do i fix this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.